# Iterate through array and get cells for all users

Tags: powershell

I have an array which looks like this: (imported from simple CSV file)

```
path                email address
\\server\file1      email1@asdf
\\server2\file3     email2@asdf
\\server4\file4     email3@asdf
\\server9\file5     email2@asdf
\\server3\file8     email2@asdf
```

I am trying to create a Powershell script which will give me for one email address all the paths.
I want to be able to say, this email address has these paths.
The problem is that some email addresses are same. In this example it's `email2@asdf`.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: What have you tried so far, where did it go wrong, and can you post the code? If you've *not* tried anything so far, you might want to have a read up on the ```Group-Object``` cmdlet - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not provided all of the requirements or attempted any scripting, we are left with making assumptions. A simple solution is to use [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) or [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7). There are different ways to utilize the commands and one may be better than another depending on the requirements.

**Looking Up Paths for a Known Email:**

```
$csv = Import-Csv file.csv
($csv | Where 'email address' -eq 'email2@asdf').path
```

**Grouping Paths Based on a List of Emails:**

```
$csv = Import-Csv file.csv
$csv | Group-Object 'email address' | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Name # an email address
    $_.Group.path # all paths for the email address
    "Email address {0} has the paths {1}" -f $_.Name,($_.Group.Path -join ',') # Output message
}
```